# How to import pandas df as variable into html

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I am using flask to write an app that displays a pandas df on part of a webpage. Here is my html template:

```
<!--user_input.html-->
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user_input" value="{{ user_input }}">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <img src="/static/plot1.png" alt="Plot Image">
        <img src="/static/plot2.png" alt="Plot Image">
        <table cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <tr>
              {% for column in df.columns %}
              <th style="width:500px;">{{ column }}</th>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% for row in df.itertuples() %}
            <tr>
              {% for value in row %}
              <td style="width500px;">{{ value }}</td>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the part of my python code that calls this template:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_message = request.form['user_input']
        df = pd.read_csv(f'data.csv')
        return render_template('user_input.html', user_input=input_message, df=df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'df' is undefined
```

Why is this, I thought I was passing `df` into the HTML template with `df=df`.

Comment: Can you include the code where you define `df`?

Comment: I just included the code, does that help?

Comment: Is it possible this error occurs via GET requests? Your code only defines `df` for POST requests. I'm not sure ... it seems like you are allowing GET requests but not handling them? Or is there another route for this page?